# Displaying a column of database in select box

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have a MySQL database named 'fishdata' and within it, a table called 'Fish', which looks like this:

---

FishType | X_B      | X_SB |

| sardine | 1#2#3       | 7#4#6|

| cod     | 3#6#8       | 7#4#6|

| catfish | 4#3#8       | 7#4#6|

---

I am trying to display all the entries in the column 'FishType' as options in a select box. This is my code:

```
<html>
<body>
    <select> 
        <?php
            $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","fishdata");
            // Check connection
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            }
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM Fish";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql)or die(mysqli_error());
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            {
            ?>
            <option value = "<?php echo($row['FishType'])?>" >
                <?php echo($row['FishType']) ?>
            </option>
            <?php
            }               
        ?>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

However, the select box is showing up with no options. Any thoughts?

Comment: 1. Why don't you just select `Fishtype`? 2. Your while-loop closes immediately.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
 echo "<option value='" . $row['FishType'] . "'>" . $row['FishType'] . "</option>";
}
```

You've got an extra bracket next to your while loop.

**EDIT**

```
<html>
<head></head> 
<body>
    <?php $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","fishdata"); 
         if (mysqli_connect_errno()){ echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); }
         $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT FishType FROM Fish");   
         if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
             echo "Records found";
             echo "<select>";

             while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
                 echo "<option value='Test'>Test</option>";
                 echo "<option value=\"" . $row['FishType'] . "\">" . $row['FishType'] . "</option>"; 
             } 
             echo "</select>";
         }
         mysqli_close($con); 
    ?> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @lm93 Hmm, try putting a hard coded option in the while loop, just to see if it's even hitting the loop. So after the bracket do something like `<option value='Test'>Test</option>`

Comment: Now the option in the select box comes up as " .$row['FishType']. "

Comment: @lm93, can you show me the code you wrote for that?

Comment: `<html>
 <select> 
    <?php
  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","fishdata");
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT FishType FROM Fish");
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
   <option value='Test'>Test</option>
   echo "<option value='" . $row['FishType'] . "'>" . $row['FishType'] . "</option>";
   }
  mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
    </select>
</html>`

Comment: @lm93 I'll update my answer, then try it out. It won't be the final answer, but it'll help us debug it.

Comment: it isn't echoing "Records found", yet it added 'Test' and " . $row['FishType']. " to the select box..very confused

Comment: @lm93 oh, derp, we were echoing a string into the select, so the HTML would've looked like: `<select>Records found <option value='test'>.... </select>`, which is not possible. Anyway, I've reupdated my answer, try it now.

Comment: This is printing on the page along with the select box:                                        0){ echo "Records found"; echo ""; } mysqli_close($con); ?>

Comment: We should probably enclose the entire thing in a `body` tag... once again, ive updated my answer..

Comment: Didn't make a difference :/